# What is correct answer for the question "Do you have..."?

Tags: syntax, do-support

What is the correct answer for the question "Do you have" (For example: Do you have money?")

options that I thought about:

> a) Yes, I do.
>
> b) Yes, I do have.
>
> c) something else?

I know that the correct answer for the question "Do you like it" is "Yes, I do" or "No, I don't".  But in this case I have doubt because of the word "have".

Comment: Could you define "appropriate"?

Comment: Ok, I'll change this word, I think it's better. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I do have* is emphatic. (Like saying *I really have money.*)
The short answer in most cases is just *Yes, I do.*

Short answers are ellipted so that you don't have to repeat the whole sentence:

> — *Do you have money?*
>   — ***Yes, I do*** <s>have money.</s>

Answer (score 4):

Here are some good answers to the question, "Do you have money?"

> 1. Yes.
> 2. Yes, I do.
> 3. Yes, I have money.
> 4. Yes, I have five dollars.

As Ustanak points out,

> 5. Yes, I do have money.

is grammatically correct, but it is only natural when one wants to make an emphatic response.

To my (American) ear, the following sentence is only natural in the past tense, not in the present tense:

> 6. Yes, I have.

Sentence 6 is natural in the following context:

> Have you stopped by the ATM?
>   Yes, I have.

The "Yes, " is optional in answers 2 - 6.

Comment: Jasper@ Can the short answer "Yes, I have" be another option ?

Comment: I think "Yes, I do have money." would be a normal answer, but "Yes, I do have." sounds weird.